# asp-page url is empty

Tags: c#, razor-pages

For some reason my `asp-page` generated url is empty

Here's my URL:

`<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/SignIn">Sign In</a>`

or

`<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="SignIn">Sign In</a>`

Here's the declaration of route in my SignIn.cshtml:

```
@page "/SignIn"
```

It works when I manually enter `localhost:5000/SignIn`

but it the generated url in HTML is empty

`<a class="nav-link text-dark" href="">Sign In</a>`

[image]

Anybody has an idea what's wrong? thanks in advance

Comment: Does the `SignIn` page have any route-parameters? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889111/link-not-rendering-when-using-asp-page-taghelper

Comment: @Dai none, it's just pure Get

Comment: @tezzly should it be asp-page="/Account/SignIn"?

Comment: @tontonsevilla you're right, thanks! please write it as an asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the asp-page value to

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-page="/Account/SignIn">Sign In</a>
```

Because your SignIn.cshtml is on the Account folder.

I hope it helps. Cheers!