# Anchor Tag Helper with Route Data

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I have the following file structure:

- **Areas** *directory*

  - **Users** *directory*

    - Index.cshtml
    - Index.cshtml.cs
    - **Edit** *directory*

      - UserEdit.cshtml
      - UserEdit.cshtml.cs

The route for the users index page is `/users`. The route for a given user's edit page is `/users/{userId}/edit`. The routes are setup with routing within the razor page like `@page "/users"`

I'm trying to use anchor tag helpers to link between the index page and the edit page(s). However, the standards marked in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper) don't seem to work unless I'm missing something. Is there a way to use anchor tag helpers to route between pages that have route data?

Note that I am using razor pages with models. I am not using controllers, and my routing is not using named routes.

With the example given below, the "edit" link's URL just keeps me at the index page.

### Index.cshtml

```
@page "/users"
@model MyApp.Areas.Users.Pages.IndexModel

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(User user in this.Model.Users)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@user.Username</td>
                <td><a asp-page="/Edit" asp-route-userId="@user.UserId">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Edit.cshtml

```
@page "/users/{userId}/edit"
@model MyApp.Areas.Users.Pages.Edit.UserEditModel

<div>The user edit page for @this.Model.User.Username</div>
```

## Edit - 8/31/2021

Adding more information around how routing is configured in my application.

### Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddCookieTempDataProvider(opt =>
        {
            opt.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        })
        .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

    services.AddControllers(opt =>
    {
        AuthorizationPolicy _policy = new()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(_policy);
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...

    app.UseHttpRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseRouting();

    ...

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

I have a `_ViewImports.cshtml` in both my base `Pages` directory and within my `Areas\Users` directory.

### ~\Pages\_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@namespace MyApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

### ~\Areas\Users\_ViewImports.cshtml

```
@namespace MyApp.Areas.Users
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: Hi @JED, could you please share how do you configure razor pages route in Startup.cs? What is the generate url of the anchor in html? Did you add `_ViewImports.cshtml` in areas or Users folder?

Comment: Hi @Rena I've added the requested info to the original question.

Comment: Hi @JED, the name should be `_ViewImports.cshtml` instead of `Users_ViewImports.cshtml` and `Pages_ViewImports.cshtml`. What's the generated html code for the anchor, could you please share with us?

Comment: The file names were messed up by stackoverflow's markup. The generated anchor tag is '<a href="~/users">Edit</a>' (except it's an absolute URL not a relative one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [Link not rendering when using asp-page TagHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889111/link-not-rendering-when-using-asp-page-taghelper),
you have to specify the name of the `cshtml` file in the `asp-page` tag property, like:

```
<a asp-page="Users/Edit/UserEdit" asp-route-userId="@user.UserId">Edit</a>
```